# Match first and last "yes" as well as all "no"

Tags: regex, pcre, pcre2

I need PCRE2 regex to find all occurences of "no" as well as first and last occurences of "yes".

Expected results:

```
"no/yes" - expect two matches: "no" and "yes"
"no/yes/word/yes/no" - expect four matches: "no", "yes", "yes", "no"
"yes/yes/no/word/yes" - expect three matches: first "yes", "no", third "yes"
"yes/no/yes/yes" - expect three matches: first "yes", "no", third "yes"
```

I try [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/6UKBZz/1) but it don't work as expected with "yes/no/yes/yes".

This subtask can make me happy with [main goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73930041/one-regex-to-replace-some-different-things).

Comment: @Poul Bak, I try this regex. Unfortunately it compiles with error "A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width". I ask Michail to check this. He confirm that he have this error too.

Comment: Different matches can be replaced with different values as Michail show in prev topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73930041/one-regex-to-replace-some-different-things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your desired result, if you can use PCRE2 [replacement string conditionals](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replaceconditional.html). You can use this regex (whitespace added for clarity, either use the `x` flag or delete the newlines between alternations):

```
(no)|
(yes)(?!.*yes)|
((?!(?=(?<a>[\s\S]*))(?<b>yes.*(?=\k<a>\z)|(?<=(?=x^|(?&b))[\s\S])))yes)
```

It matches one of:

- `(no)` : `no` (captured in group 1)
- `(yes)(?!.*yes)` : `yes` not followed by `yes` (captured in group 2)
- `((?!(?=(?<a>[\s\S]*))(?<b>yes.*(?=\k<a>\z)|(?<=(?=x^|(?&b))[\s\S])))yes)` : this is the equivalent of a variable length negative lookbehind for `(?<!yes.*)(yes)` with the `yes` captured in group 3. For the derivation of this part of the regex, see this [blog post](http://www.drregex.com/2019/02/variable-length-lookbehinds-actually.html).

You can then use conditional replacements, replacing group 1 with `-` and groups 2 and 3 with `+`

```
${1:+-:+}
```

For input of

```
no/yes
no/yes/yes/no
/yes/yes/no/yes
no/word/no/yes/yes/yes/no
yes/no
yes/no/yes/word/yes
/word/yes/no/no/no/yes/yes
yes/no/yes/yes
```

This gives:

```
-/+
-/+/+/-
/+/yes/-/+
-/word/-/+/yes/+/-
+/-
+/-/yes/word/+
/word/+/-/-/-/yes/+
+/-/yes/+
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jFVTNo/7)

Comment: Wow!! Your answer is divine. It doing exactly what I want. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Nick, your answer is really great +! I know performance is not Klee's concern. However  it seems ``(no)|yes(?!.*yes)|((?<!yes|(?!(?2)).))yes`` may also be used with the same idea https://regex101.com/r/C7TSHp/1

Comment: Thank a lot, Michail. This one works too.

Comment: @Michail that is brilliant - much simpler! you really should post that as an answer. I should have removed my capture groups 2 & 3, I was originally matching everything and so needed them, but the final one does not.

Comment: @klee I'm glad I could help - but if Michail posts his comment as an answer you should definitely accept that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are overthinking it.
There is no real point in using ONE regex to replace them all.
Just use multiple regexes.

```js
s.replace(/yes/, '+').replace(/yes(?!.*yes)/, '+').replaceAll(/no/g, '-')
```

Also, there's no real way to replace one entry exept replacing it

Comment: Thank you. But the private application I use does not give me access to the programming language. I only have access to the input of ONE regular expression with which I can process the text. To perform several tasks, I have to complicate this regular expression